# Syntax Error in Insert Statement

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm new to Database connection and when I am having a problem with the `cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()` line it says there is a syntax error with the INSERT INTO statement and I can't figure out what the problem is:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class txtNotes
    Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand

    Dim strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\CourseworkDB"
    'the name of the database goes in here'

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
        cnnOLEDB.Open()

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddFirstName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddFirstName.Click
        If txtFirstName.Text <> "" Then

            MsgBox(cmdInsert.CommandText)
            cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer (First Name) VALUES (" & txtFirstName.Text & ", '"
            cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Else
            MsgBox("Enter the required values:" & vbNewLine & "1. First Name")
        End If
        cmdInsert.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I Strongly suggest not getting into a routine of building SQL strings by concatinating strings together.  You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL-Injection, especially if this is web based.  You should build your commands with place-holder parameters in the string, then add the parameters to the command object.  Add the parameters in the same sequence as they would appear in the command... such as

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ( @parmFirstName, @parmLastName )"
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@parmFirstName", txtFirstName.Text );
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@parmLastName", txtLastName.Text );
```

> If your field names have embedded spaces, different databases work
>   differently, some requires single backtick (the key left of the number
>   1) around the field.  such as 'first name'.  Some use square brackets,
>   such as [first name].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`"INSERT INTO Customer (First Name) VALUES ('" & txtFirstName.Text & "')"`

Answer (score 0):

Warning: [Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) is watching you.

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = _
"INSERT INTO Customer (First Name) VALUES ('" & txtFirstName.Text & "')"
```